# Update action from Index controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best practice for organizing Show, Update, Create and Delete within the MVC? I'd like to perform an update action from the index controller and before I commit any time to it I'd like to consider this. Basically I want users to be able to tag articles from the index.

Is it a bad practice to do an update action from the index?

What are some things I need to consider?

**update**

This is in fact an update action, because I have constructed a HABTM association between to models with a join table. I'm simply looking for design thoughts on performing an update action from the Index. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are asking if it is OK to call the **update** action from the **index** page. Yes, that is a normal thing to do.

One way to call the **update** action on the index page is with the **link_to** method.

= link_to('Yes', my_model_url(my_model, :my_param => true), { :method => :put })

Using the method **put** to a URL of the form /my_model/id goes to the controller's **update** action.